# MOOC - for causal analysis - no statistics background

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, statistics

Am a software guy with no background in causal inference.

While I am now familiar with prediction techniques due to the plethora of courses available online, I would like to seek recommendations from people here for causal inference.

As you might know, how prediction techniques tutorials are available in a way that can be consumed by people from a software background, I would like to learn causal inference techniques like Propensity Score Matching, Comparative Effectiveness Research, epidemiology analytics, effect estimates, Hazard Ratios, Odd ratios, etc in a proper course which can take us from beginner to advanced curriculum. Basically, things that are used in observational healthcare research and public health fields. Are there any courses like what Udacity offers for Data Science (which only deals with Prediction problems)? Am looking for a similar course that can take us from A-Z of causal analysis.

Can you guys direct me to some resources where I can learn such techniques? Doesn't really have to be a degree but can also be online tutorials or Youtube series

Comment: cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/531681/232706

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even i am getting accustomed with concepts of causal inference and working on it's use case for telecom data. Sharing some of the resources which might be helpful to you:

- [Causalnex Package](https://causalnex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Pyro](https://docs.pyro.ai/en/dev/contrib.cevae.html) Tutorials https://github.com/altdeep/causalML
- https://github.com/DeekshaD/causalML-lecturenotes (Notes of the [course](https://bookdown.org/robertness/causalml/docs/))

Some courses though they may be stat heavy:

- [Introduction to Causal Inference](https://www.bradyneal.com/causal-inference-course)
- [Causal Inference](https://causalinference.gitlab.io/)

Looking forward to more suggestions from the community :)

Comment: thanks, useful to know. Upvoted

Comment: Did you take up altdeep course? Do you know how much do they charge?

Comment: This is other one I found - https://shubhanshu.com/awesome-causality/

Comment: No I haven't taken it their Curriculum looks interesting though